# Angular 6 - How can I hide a div onclick of outside of that div

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a button and a div,When I click the button the div is used to toggle.But I need to hide the div also when I click outside of that div.Here the code below.

### app.component.html

```
<button (click) ="clickit()">Click here</button>
<div style="border:1px solid;height:200px;width:200px;" *ngIf="show">Toggle hide and show</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name: string = '2019-01-01T23-00-11';
  //name: string = '2019-01-01';
  show:any;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
clickit(){
this.show = !this.show;
}
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to get the click event of document.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onDocumentClick(event) {
  this.show = false;
}
```

Please make sure you added `$event.stopPropagation()` in your `clickit()` function.

You should add `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` to the div as well.

Comment: Right, but the element is inside document. How are you checking to make sure the target of the event is not the div in question?

Comment: $event.stopPropagation() is to prevent the triggering click event of document.

Comment: Okay sure. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqseru clicking on the inside of the div closes it also though. The goal is to only close is when clicking outside the div. You can use DOM methods such as `Element.closest()` or `Element.contains()` to check if the click target is the div or inside the div to avoid closing it when it is clicked.

Comment: Add `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` to the div.

Comment: That definitely works. You should update your question to show that. You got my upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Add `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on div for stop bubbling effect

```
<div style="border:1px solid;height:200px;width:200px;" *ngIf="show" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >Toggle hide and show</div>
```

Try this by using **HostListener**

```
 import { Component , HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {
  name: string = '2019-01-01T23-00-11';
  //name: string = '2019-01-01';
  show:any;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])

    clickout() {
     this.show = false;
    }




  ngOnInit() {

  }
    clickit(){
    this.show = !this.show;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but the element is inside document. How are you checking to make sure the target of the event is not the div in question?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky for stop bubbling effect we need to apply stop propagation. Thanks i have updated

Answer (score 4):

Try This
HTML

```
<div class="d-flex p-2 links">
    <a (click)="showPopup(1,$event)"><img src="../../assets/icons/toolbar/settings.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="user-mention" *ngIf="opened == true" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
      <div class="listing"> {{userEmail}}</div>
      <div class="listing" (click)="logout()">Logout</div>
  </div>
```

TS Code

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onDocumentClick(event) {
    this.showPopup(2,event);
    event.stopPropagation()  
  }



opened: any = false;
  showPopup(id, event) {
    if(id == 1) {
      this.opened = true;
      event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
      this.opened = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If possible, you should always mention addition information for better understanding to new user

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using angular Directive

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @Output() clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }
        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown" (click)="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" (clickOutside)="dropdownOpen = false">
...
</div>
```

**Note:** Using this directive too much can cause slowness. Since each click, no matter where it is on the page